# Can IEEE, Elsevier, Springer detect multiple submissions to their journals?

Tags: paper-submission

If one wants to submit one's manuscript to multiple journals of a publisher (IEEE, Elsevier, Springer etc.), is it possible for a publisher to detect it? I mean if any publisher keeps a database of submitted manuscripts to crosscheck newly submitted manuscripts with the existing ones.

Comment: Plagiarism is excluded in the question because plag. means to crosscheck with already published work.

Comment: From one of the IEEE transactions: "IEEE takes the protection of intellectual property seriously. Accordingly, all submissions are filtered by CrossCheck, a powerful plagiarism detection software system. By submitting your work you agree to allow IEEE to screen your work. When plagiarism is detected, penalties can be severe and may include strict banning from publishing in all IEEE titles."

Comment: I'm wondering why this question was downvoted.

Comment: Related (actually, almost duplicate): [How do conferences detect double submission?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/98405/how-do-conferences-detect-double-submission)

Comment: I wonder why you ask. Are you intending to do this?

Comment: @Buffy Yes. I need my work to be reviewed by as many experts as possible within short span of time.

Comment: It is an extremely dangerous act. I recommend against it. Your reputation will probably suffer. If it is found out by anyone, it will likely be soon known by everyone.

Comment: @Daniel  If I had to guess, I would guess the down vote is due to the answer to Buffy's comment. Multi-submission is kind of aggravating. I would urge the OP not to do it, even if the chance of getting caught soon is small. Sooner or later you are likely to be in front of some kind of evaluation committee, for a job or a grant or something. And this sort of thing can suddenly jump up and bite you hard.

Comment: In the light of insightful comments and advices, I have changed my mind. Thanks to all.

Comment: @puppetsockreinstateMonica The downvote happened before my previous comment (and before Buffy's comment/question). I see nothing wrong with the OP's question hence my previous comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surprisingly enough, they probably can't. Modern Editorial Management Systems can detect multiple submissions to the same journal, even if the previous submission was years ago, but the EMS still only works for that one journal. Inter-journal sharing does happen, but as far as I'm aware, it's not common and even then it's often only the reviewer pool. The editors of one journal cannot see which manuscripts are submitted to the other journal.

If you are detected by the publisher, the most likely reason is because one of the production staff handles both journals and noticed it. Alternatively, it's possible the editors of both journals invited the same reviewer who noticed it.

Comment: Depending on how narrow the relevant field is, there might also be a good chance that both editors pick the same reviewer, which will equally be noticed. All in all, it sounds like a good way to get blacklisted...

Comment: Good point, will add.